# How to perform different actions based on array name in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, switch-statement, associative-array

At the moment I have a function that hardcodes the array name to perform a certain action. I would like to pass the array name that needs to be processed as a function parameter, and then execute a specific action based on the array name. How can I achieve this in bash?

Now:

```sh
# array definition
declare -A array1=(
 ["a"]="apple"
 ["b"]="banana"
)

# function definition
process(){
    echo "printing letters and fruits"
    for letter in "${!array1[@]}"; do
        fruit="${array1[$letter]}"
        echo "$letter: $fruit"
    done
}

# commands
process
```

Desired (code is wrong!):

```sh
# array definition
declare -A array1=(
 ["a"]="apple"
 ["b"]="banana"
)

declare -A array2=(
 ["a"]="ant"
 ["b"]="bear"
)

# function definition
process(){
     arrayname="$1"
     case "$arrayname" in
         "array1")
             echo "printing letters and fruits"
             for letter in "${!arrayname[@]}"; do
                 fruit="${arrayname[$letter]}"
                 echo "$letter: $fruit"
             done
         ;;
         "array2") 
             echo "printing animals only"
             for letter in "${!array1[@]}"; do
                 animal="${array2[$letter]}"
                 echo "$animal"
             done
         ;;
    esac
}

# commands
process array1
process array2
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two things: First, clean up your variable names - sometimes you're using `arrayname`, sometimes `array1` or `array2` in your `process` function. Second, use [`declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare) or [`local`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-local) to make a *nameref* (A special variable that when set to the name of another variable, acts like that one):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# array definition
declare -A array1=(
 ["a"]="apple"
 ["b"]="banana"
)

declare -A array2=(
 ["a"]="ant"
 ["b"]="bear"
)

# function definition
process(){
     local -n arrayname="$1"
     case "$1" in
         "array1")
             echo "printing letters and fruits"
             for letter in "${!arrayname[@]}"; do
                 fruit="${arrayname[$letter]}"
                 echo "$letter: $fruit"
             done
         ;;
         "array2")
             echo "printing animals only"
             for letter in "${!arrayname[@]}"; do
                 animal="${arrayname[$letter]}"
                 echo "$animal"
             done
         ;;
    esac
}

# commands
process array1
process array2
```

Comment: +1 for the `-n` reference, but I think it's a bit useless considering that the code is still dispatching based on the array name using `case`.